# Integer coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

> Find the minimum amount $m$ of integer coordinates $\left(\text{in } \mathbb{R}^n\right)$ one needs to choose in order to be sure that there exist a line segment, such that its endpoints are one of the previously chosen points and its midpoint's coordinates are integer.

---

My solution:

The midpoint coordinates of line segment created by points $P = (p_1,p_2,...,p_n)$ and $Q = (q_1,q_2,...,q_n)$ is as follows:
$$
R = \left(\frac{p_1+q_1}{2},\frac{p_2+q_2}{2},...,\frac{p_n+q_n}{2}\right)
$$

In order that $R$'s coordinates are integer, the elements of pairs $(p_1,q_1),(p_2,q_2),...,(p_n,q_n)$ must be either be both odd or both even.

Let's consider a binary sequence:

$$
a(P)=(p_1\ mod\ 2,\ p_2\ mod\ 2,...,p_n\ mod\ 2)
$$

Points $P,\ Q$ meet the requirements iff $a(P)=a(Q)$.

The amount of such unique sequences is obviously equal to $2^n$.

Therefore in a set of $2^n+1$ points, there exist at least two points with the exact same sequence.

Hence $m=2^n+1$

---

Please verify this proof, and in case I made some mistake, plase give me some tips on how to correct it.

Comment: Look good. What are your concerns?

Comment: @KeeferRowan nothing in particular, just wanted to make sure

Comment: To be complete you should explicitly mention the obvious fact that it _is_ possible for a set of $2^n$ lattice points to not contain any segment whose midpoint has integer coordinates. (The vertices of an $n$-dimensional unit cube, for example.) This shows that $2^n$ is too small, which is important because you were asked to show that $2^n+1$ is the _minimum_ possible.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your construction in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie well, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we need at least 5 points, because point can be in 4 states: (odd, odd), (odd, even), (even, odd), (even, even), therefore 5th point will always have the same combination as one of the previous ones. So coordinates $(\frac{p_1+q_1}{2},\frac{p_2+q_2}{2})$ will be integer. I'm not sure if that is what you were asking for.